# Is my do while loop not working due to this function?

Tags: c, function, loops, while-loop

Im making a program where it asks the user to guess a number 1-100 that the computer is thinking about.

In the end of the program, when the user has guessed the correct number, im trying to get the program to ask if user wants to play again (restart the program).

To solve this, i tried using a `do while` loop & `char repeat;`. The loop is stretching from almost the beginning of the program, until the end, althought without success. Does anyone know what im doing wrong? Is it because of the function `talfunktion`, that the loop won't pass?

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int talfunktion (int tal, int guess, int tries, char repeat);

int main () {

do {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int tal = rand() % 100 + 1; //tal is the correct value that the code is thinking of 
    int guess; //guess is the guessed value of the user
    int tries = 0; // amount of tries it took until getting correct
    char repeat;


    printf("Psst, the right number is: %d \n", tal); // remove later, not relevant to uppg.

    printf("Im thinking of a number between 1 and 100, guess which!");
    printf("\nEnter: ");
    scanf("%d", &guess);
    guess = talfunktion(tal, guess, tries, repeat);

    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;

    }

    int talfunktion(int tal, int guess, int tries, char repeat) {
        do {
            if (guess < tal) {
                tries++;
                printf("\nYour guess is too low, try again!");
                printf("\nEnter: ");
                scanf("%d", &guess);
            }
            else if (guess > tal) {
                tries++;
                printf("\nYour guess is too high, try again!");
                printf("\nEnter: ");
                scanf("%d", &guess);
            }
        } while (guess > tal || guess < tal);

        if (guess == tal) {
            printf("\nCongratulations, that is correct!");
            tries++;
            printf("\nYou made %d attempt(s)", tries);
            printf("\nPlay Again? (y/n)");
            scanf("%c", &repeat);
    }
} while (repeat == 'y' || repeat == 'Y');


}
```

Comment: You have a `return 0;` inside your loop, so it will never loop. Also, you have a `}` that matches the `do` after that `return` with no `while` clause.

Comment: This code doesn't compile. You can't nest functions like that in C. Move the talfunktion function out of the main function's body.

Comment: Don't use a `do-while` for this. Use a `while (true)` loop, and then use `break` to get out of the loop when the user says no.

Comment: @clay0 The function declaration does not make sense. The values of Its parameters tries and repeat are not used in the function.

Comment: `guess > tal || guess < tal` is the same as saying `guess != tal`.  Also `(repeat == 'y' || repeat == 'Y')` can be reduced to `(repeat == 'y' )`

Comment: `talfunktion` cannot be defined inside another function.  In this code it is defined inside `main`

Answer (score 0):

There are several things mentioned in the comments that describe problems, 
Things you should look at:

- Do not define a function inside another function
- be careful where you place return statements
- when using character testing, use `char` type for variable
- consider simplifying your logical comparisons. (eg `guess > tal || guess < tal` is the same as `guess != tal` )
- make sure automatic variables are placed such that they are visible where used.
- Place space in format specifier: `" %c"` for `scanf()` to consume newline character.  (instead of excessive use of `getchar()`)

Here is a simplified version of your code, with modified `main` and `talfunktion` functions...

```
char talfunktion(int tal);

int main (void) {
     int tal=0;//remove from inside {...} to make it visible to rest of function
     char repeat = 'n';

     srand(time(NULL));
     tal = rand() % 100 + 1; //tal is the correct value that the code is thinking of 

    do {

            repeat = talfunktion(tal);

        }while((tolower(repeat) == 'y'));

        return 0;
}

char talfunktion(int tal)//do all relevant work in function and return 
{                        //only what is necessary
     int guess = 0;
     char repeat = 'n';


    printf("Im thinking of a number between 1 and 100, guess which!");
    printf("\nEnter a number from 1 to 100: ");
    scanf("%d", &guess);
    if((guess < 1) || (guess > 100))
    {
        printf("Entered out of bounds guess...\n");
    }
    else if (guess != tal)
    {
        if(guess < tal) printf("guess too small\n");
        else printf("guess too large\n");
        printf("Try  again? <'n' or 'y'>\n");
        scanf(" %c", &repeat);//space in format specifier to consume newline character
        if(tolower(repeat) != 'y') return 'n';//tolower() allows both upper and lower case
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Congratulations: You guessed right.\n");
        printf("Play again? <'n' or 'y'>\n");
        scanf(" %c", &repeat);
    }
    return repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one possible solution

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void talfunktion(int tal, int guess, int* tries)
{
            if (guess < tal)
            {
                (*tries)++;
                printf("\nYour guess is too low, try again!");
            }
            else if (guess > tal)
            {
                (*tries)++;
                printf("\nYour guess is too high, try again!");
            }
            else if (guess == tal)
            {
                (*tries)++;
                printf("\nCongratulations, that is correct!");
                printf("\nYou made %d attempt(s)", *tries);
            }
}

int main (void)
{
    int tal; //tal is the correct value that the code is thinking of
    int guess; //guess is the guessed value of the user
    int tries = 0; // amount of tries it took until getting correct
    char playAgain;

    do {
            srand(time(NULL));
            tal = rand() % 100 + 1; //tal is the correct value that the code is thinking of
            printf("\nIm thinking of a number between 1 and 100, guess which!");
            printf("\nEnter: ");
            scanf("%d", &guess);
            talfunktion(tal, guess, &tries);

            printf("\nPsst, the right number is: %d", tal); // remove later, not relevant to uppg.
            getchar(); //to halt the code for taking the input

            if(guess == tal)
            {
                tries = 0;
                printf("\nPlay Again? (y/n)\n");
                scanf("%c", &playAgain);
            }

    } while (playAgain != 'n');

return 0;
}
```